# how to store an array value from blade to database in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

submitting a dynamic form but can't store the value to database. im a beginner i stuck for 2,3 days but cant solve the problem.

> the request value is like
> {"_token":"PTGmyf3UZrD1TgKDJcREcKia9VFRLYaP5kNaAkAU","id":["28","31"],"name":["Fogg","zack"],"rate":["70","5000"],"quantity":["1","1"],"submit":"Submit"}

```
  <form name="" id="form" action="{{ url('/store_order_item') }}" method="POST">  
  @csrf
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Product Id</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Rate</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Amount</th>
     <th>Action</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>

  <tbody>
    
  </tbody>
    
</table> 
<h6>Grand Total: <span id= "grandtotal"></span> </h6>
<input type="button" name="" id="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Cancel">  
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" value="Submit"/>  

</form>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var i = 1;
  
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
      var button_id1 ;

    $('#button').click(function(){

  let namesearch = $('#search').val();
 
  let idsearch = $('#idsearch').val();

  if ((namesearch == '')&&(idsearch == '')){
      return false;
    }

  $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "/pos_search_ajax",
      data: { name: namesearch, id: idsearch },
    
      success: function(response) {
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row_'+i+'"><td><input id="id_'+i+'" type="text" name="id[]" value="'+response[0].id+'" readonly></td><td><input id="name_'+i+'" name="name[]" type="text" value="'+response[0].name+'" readonly></td><td> <input id="rate_'+i+'" name="rate[]" type="text" value="'+response[0].price+'" readonly></td><td><input id="quantity_'+i+'" onchange="change('+i+')" name="quantity[]" type="number" min=1 value="1"></td><td class="total" id="total_'+i+'" name="total[]">'+response[0].price+'</td><td>  <button type="button" onclick="remove_tr('+i+')"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></td></tr>'); 
        
        total();
       
        i++; 
      }   
  }); 

# this is the Controller #

public function store(Request $request)
    {  
        foreach($request->all() as $itm)
        {
            $items = New OrderItem();
            $items->product_id = $request->id;
            $items->name = $request->name;
            $items->save();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your `request` always formatted like that, then using `foreach($request->all() as $itm)` will only return what you send, value of `id` will be `["28","31"]` and so on. So you could try something like this:

```php
$data = $request->all();
for ($i=0; $i < count($data['id']); $i++) { 
    $item = new OrderItem();
    $item->product_id = $data['id'][$i];
    $item->name = $data['name'][$i];
    $item->save();
}
```

That code will iterate over an `id`, and the product name must be in the same order as the id.

Comment: i got this while replacing  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: @thtom Updated. Try `$data` as array instead of object.

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object. still got this

Comment: Then you have to make sure, if the data sent to the server. Try adding `dd($data);` before `for` statement

Comment: array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "7nKh4HBCFqKKIQFz2HUplzZg987HQ1wVzNmsCG1F"
  "id" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "31"
    1 => "30"
  ]
  "name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "zack"
    1 => "xzmen"
  ]
  "rate" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "5000"
    1 => "5000"
  ]
  "quantity" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
  ]
  "submit" => "Submit"
]

Comment: i got that when dd($data)

Comment: @thtom Updated. it should be `for ($i=0; $i < count($data['id']); $i++)`

Comment: @thtom you're welcome. You may mark it as correct so someone with the same problem could easily know it.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple request parameter with same name needs additional array symbol(`[]`) on its name attirbute, and u did it right way like `<input name="name[]" ...`.
This makes parameter that is array. (not a single value)

So u when u access the parameter, u need to access 1 more depth using index number(to get nth item).
To access all the items, u need to loop that parameter.

And parameters is not only one(`id`, `name`, `rate`, `quantity`), it is need that a parameter to be basis to loop.
The basis parameter could be anything, but normally identifiers preferred. (eg, id)

And the code to write ur own is something like @TheArka's answer.
But recommend u know how's going on, why does it do.